# pressesBegan not called in Playground Book

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground, mac-catalyst

I need to respond to keys being pressed on a physical keyboard, but the method `pressesBegan` is not being called on any class. I've tried putting it inside my SKScene and my ViewController, but it just is not getting recognized

**UPDATE** Here is the code, I've replaced the logic with `fatalError()`, so that the book will crash when `pressesBegan` gets called. Since it's not crashing, `pressesBegan` is not being called

The rest of the code has nothing related to responders

```swift
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import SceneKit
import UIKit

public class GameScene: SKScene {
    
  // ... some code
    
    public override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    /// Some more code...
}


class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func loadView(){
        self.view = sceneView
    }

    let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 1920, height: 1080))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            
            // Present the scene
            sceneView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
    
    public override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        fatalError()
    }
}

let viewController = GameViewController()
viewController.view.becomeFirstResponder()

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: You will need to show some more code

Comment: @aheze updated the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by adding `override var canBecomeFirstResponder { true }` to the `UIViewController`, calling `myViewController.becomeFirstResponder()` after presenting the controller and calling `super.pressesBegan` when I'm not handling the press